# Какой адрес писать в теге rel canonical?

Tags: html, seo

Подскажите пожалуйста, проверил сайт на правильность в `sitechecker.pro`, и он выдал warning:

```
Canonical link check: canonical link tag not found
```

Погуглив изучил, что это тег, который помогает поисковикам выделить главную страницу из дублирующихся.

Мой сайт `trenajor.me` не подразумевает продажу товара и там не будет акций которые будут дублировать страницу товара и т.д.

Я правильно понимаю, что дублями в данном случае будут страницы с `https://www.мойсайт` и без www `https://мойсайт` и тогда поисковику нужно сказать о странице, чтобы он среди этих двух дублей выделил главную?

То есть если моя страница `https://trenajor.me/index.html` мне в теге `<head>` в линке каноникал ее же и прописать?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://trenajor.me/index.html">
```

Пожалуйста подскажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> То есть, если моя страница https://trenajor.me/index.html, то мне в теге canonical ее же и прописать?

Да, Вы прописываете тот адрес, который считаете основным:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://trenajor.me/index.html" />
```

*Так же стоит правильно настроить перенаправление на сервере, что бы он не путал поисковики в случае `www` и `non-www`, если Вы пользуетесь только чем то одним.*

Comment: Василий! А trenajor.me/index.html нужно редиректорить на trenajor.me А то у меня показывает дублирование description и tittle в этих двух документах

Comment: @Дима ответил на Ваш вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166623/397819)

Answer (score 0):

> Какой адрес писать в теге rel canonical?

Тот УРЛ который вы желаете видеть в результатах поиска. Это будет соответствовать **[следующей рекомендации Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)**:

> **Для чего выбирать канонический URL?**
>
> Указывать каноническую страницу из
> числа одинаковых или похожих стоит в следующих случаях:
>
> Если нужно выбрать, какой URL следует показывать в результатах поиска.

Comment: Мне понравилась эта статья. Вы получили рыбку на почту?