# Как убрать ошибку дублирования tittle и description?

Tags: html, seo, redirect

Программа проверки сайта выдает, что у меня дублируется `tittle` и `description` для страниц моего сайта `https://trenajor.me` и `https://trenajor.me/index.html`.

Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно сделать редирект, в данном случае c `/index.html` в `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно сделать redirect, в данном случае c
> `/index.html` на `/`?

Да, Вам нужно настроить сервер так что бы у каждой страницы был "основной" адрес, соответственно сделать выбор:

```
// http или https
// www или non-www 
// index или non-index 
// html-extension или non-html-extrension
// и т.д.
```

*Так же стоит прописать [канононический адрес](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166600/397819) в заголовке каждой страницы.*

Comment: Дополню - неплохо бы также указать canonical

Comment: Спасибо. С помощью умных людей внес изменения в .htaccess

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trenajor\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.trenajor.me/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]  только теперь в компарсере выдает 301 MovedPermanently для двух страниц http://trenajor.me/ и https://trenajor.me/  Как с этим быть подскажите

Comment: @Дима Вам следует создать для этого отдельный вопрос